# How to read text file's key, value pair using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, key

I want to parse one text file which contains following data.

**Input.txt-**

```
1=88|11=1438|15=KKK|45=7.7|45=00|21=66|86=a
4=13|4=1388|49=DDD|8=157.73|67=00|45=08|84=b|45=k
6=84|41=18|56=TTT|67=1.2|4=21|45=78|07=d
```

In this input text file no columns are fixed it may be 10 or 20 or anything. I want to parse this file using pandas. Output should contain :

**output.txt-**

```
index[0]
1     88
11    1438
15    kkk
45    7.7
45    00
21    66
86    a

index[1]
4     13
4     1388
49    DDD
8     157.73
67    00
45    08
84    b
45    k
```

Any suggestions about how I can get this type of result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with separator which is not in data e.g. `;`, then double [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

temp=u"""1=88|11=1438|15=KKK|45=7.7|45=00|21=66|86=a
4=13|4=1388|49=DDD|8=157.73|67=00|45=08|84=b|45=k
6=84|41=18|56=TTT|67=1.2|4=21|45=78|07=d
"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=";", index_col=None, names=['text'])

print (df)
                                                text
0        1=88|11=1438|15=KKK|45=7.7|45=00|21=66|86=a
1  4=13|4=1388|49=DDD|8=157.73|67=00|45=08|84=b|45=k
2           6=84|41=18|56=TTT|67=1.2|4=21|45=78|07=d
```

```
s = df.text.str.split('|', expand=True).stack().str.split('=', expand=True)
print (s)
      0       1
0 0   1      88
  1  11    1438
  2  15     KKK
  3  45     7.7
  4  45      00
  5  21      66
  6  86       a
1 0   4      13
  1   4    1388
  2  49     DDD
  3   8  157.73
  4  67      00
  5  45      08
  6  84       b
  7  45       k
2 0   6      84
  1  41      18
  2  56     TTT
  3  67     1.2
  4   4      21
  5  45      78
  6  07       d
```

```
dfs = [g.set_index(0).rename_axis(None) for i, g in s.groupby(level=0)]
print (dfs[0])
       1
1     88
11  1438
15   KKK
45   7.7
45    00
21    66
86     a
```

```
for i, g in s.groupby(level=0):
    print (g.set_index(0).rename_axis(None))
       1
1     88
11  1438
15   KKK
45   7.7
45    00
21    66
86     a
         1
4       13
4     1388
49     DDD
8   157.73
67      00
45      08
84       b
45       k
      1
6    84
41   18
56  TTT
67  1.2
4    21
45   78
07    d
```

EDIT by comment:

If need write to file `s`, use [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Datarame.to_csv.html):

```
s.to_csv('file.txt', header=None, index=None, sep='\t')
```

EDIT1 by comment:

You can set column name to empty string and remove index name by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`), but more common is set column name to some text (e.g. `s.columns = ['idx','a']`):

```
s = df.text.str.split('|', expand=True).stack().str.split('=', expand=True)
s.columns = ['idx','']
print (s)
    idx        
0 0   1      88
  1  11    1438
  2  15     KKK
  3  45     7.7
  4  45      00
  5  21      66
  6  86       a
1 0   4      13
  1   4    1388
  2  49     DDD
  3   8  157.73
  4  67      00
  5  45      08
  6  84       b
  7  45       k
2 0   6      84
  1  41      18
  2  56     TTT
  3  67     1.2
  4   4      21
  5  45      78
  6  07       d
dfs = [g.set_index('idx').rename_axis(None) for i, g in s.groupby(level=0)]
print (dfs[0])
1     88
11  1438
15   KKK
45   7.7
45    00
21    66
86     a
```

Comment: Dang!  You beat me again ;-) +1

Comment: @jezrael- Everything fine but I don't want this 1 and 0 which is printing above output. what we can do for this? edit answer and provide some top level explanation.

Comment: @kit you should do that yourself SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: @shivsn- I'm not asking about code or answer. I'm asking for suggestions.

Comment: @kit - Do you need write to file `s` - only columns `0` and `1` without header and index? Then use `s.to_csv('file.txt', header=None, index=None, sep='\t')`.

Comment: @kit - Can I add write to csv to answer and remove list comprehension?

Comment: @jezrael- yes you can add this stuff but don't remove list comprehension. This is also useful for other

Comment: @jezrael- I want this list implementation and how can I remove this index 0 and 1 from this dfs? I dont want to write directly s to the csv file because I want to add index[0] and index[1] like stuff between columns.

Comment: @jezrael- Next revision of this task - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371440/how-to-split-key-value-from-text-file-using-pandas?noredirect=1#comment64154019_38371440]