# read file with pandas and create header

Tags: python, database, pandas, file

I have several txt files that are formatted in this way

```
label1: value1 label2: string1 date: 2018-06-26 label3: value2 label4: string
```

I would like to read those files and create a database
where I have headers and then values/strings
which then I write to file.
any help?
regards

Comment: Use pandas read_csv to read the text files and then merge all these into one dataframe

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: dataset_cormat = pd.read_csv('cormat_out.txt', delimiter=" ", header=None, names=["shot", "user", "date",'seq','written by']), but it's not what I want as it cannot divide the data according to headers i set

Comment: What is the separator between columns? Is it just space like between column name and value, or that is tab? If it is different from just space, you might find here the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366494/how-to-read-text-files-key-value-pair-using-pandas (just change | to tab and = to : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if data is exactly similar to this:

Age: 39 Name: Jack date: 2018-06-26 Region: NY Open: Yes
Age: 21 Name: Rose date: 2018-09-16 Region: TX Open: NO

You need to split texts based on the SPACES in the lines.

```
import pandas as pd

f=open('D:\\1.txt','r')
datalist=[]
dlabels=[]
for line in f:
    words = line.split(' ')
    words[-1] = words[-1][:-1]
    if len(dlabels)==0:
        for i in range(0,len(words),2):
            dlabels.append(words[i][:-1])
    tempL=[]
    for i in range(0,len(words),2):
        tempL.append(words[i+1])
    datalist.append(tempL)        
f.close()

data=pd.DataFrame(datalist,columns=dlabels)
print(data)
```

output:
  Age  Name        date Region   Open
0  39  Jack  2018-06-26     NY  Yes
1  21  Rose  2018-09-16     TX     NO

Comment: thanks @DataScienceStep that worked. I just had to edit the name of the label has it had a space. I am able to create dataFrame!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a mapping between identifier labels and values. You can convert this into a dictionary via standard Python:

```
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""label1: value1 label2: string1 date: 2018-06-26 label3: value2 label4: string""")

# replace mystr with open('file.csv', 'r')
with mystr as fin:
    data = next(fin).strip().split()
    data_dict = {i[:-1]: j for i, j in zip(data[::2], data[1::2])}

print(data_dict)

{'date': '2018-06-26',
 'label1': 'value1',
 'label2': 'string1',
 'label3': 'value2',
 'label4': 'string'}
```

From here there are many options depending on the exact format you want to output your data, e.g. `pandas`, `csv`, etc. You need to provide more details for help with this step, but first you should investigate these options:

- [How do I write a Python dictionary to a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373247/how-do-i-write-a-python-dictionary-to-a-csv-file)
- [Python Dictionary to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331469/python-dictionary-to-csv)